# Different results between Wolfram and Numpy when I multiply 3 matrices?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, wolfram-mathematica, matrix-multiplication, eigenvector

Firstly, I am sure that the Wolfram answer is the correct one because the two sandwich matrices is the eigen vecors matrices so the answer has to to be in the form of eigne bases.

so, the question is, what did i do wrong in the python code? is it the square roots of 5? is there a way to write them correctly?

Wolfram (Correct Answer):

[image: Correct]

Python Code (Wrong Answer):

[image: Wrong]

In python, I tried another three matrices, that does not contain any elements with square roots, it gave the correct answer, so I think my problem is how to write them correctly in the matrix?

Comment: Your numpy answer is also correct. Floating point numbers have a finite precision, so you won't get exactly zeros in the off-diagonal elements.

Comment: Matt Pitkin, Thank you very much, I actually did not see the (e-16) at the end of the diagonal elements!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code / text. They are less readable than code posted [with the correct formatting](/help/formatting), and don't allow people to copy them into their own editors if they want to test something

Comment: Okay @pho , Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wolfram does symbolic computation. Numpy numerical.

If you want to compare comparable things, you need to use symbolic computation on python side as well

```py
import sympy
A = sympy.matrices.Matrix([[2,2],[1+sympy.sqrt(5), 1-sympy.sqrt(5)]])
B = sympy.matrices.Matrix([[0,1],[1,1]])
C = A**-1

sympy.pretty_print(sympy.simplify(C @ B @ A))
```

→

```
⎡1   √5        ⎤
⎢─ + ──    0   ⎥
⎢2   2         ⎥
⎢              ⎥
⎢        1   √5⎥
⎢  0     ─ - ──⎥
⎣        2   2 ⎦
```

Comment: Cool, Thank you chrslg, I'll definitely use this module